# Разрешение зависимости без ServiceLocator

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Возьмем простой пример - база городов. Сделаем интерфейс обработчика городов, который, в частности, должен сохранять информацию о городе. Получится что-то такое:

```
interface ICitiesHandler
{
    Save(City city);
    ...
}
```

И где-то опишем его реализацию (нас она не интересует). Зарегистрировали его в DI-контейнере. Я использую `MVVMLight`. При его добавлении в проект он создает такой вот класс (в нем мы и регистрируем наш обработчик):

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            // Create design time view services and models
            //SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DesignDataService>();
        }
        else
        {

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ICitiesHandler, CitiesHandler>(); // Регистрируем обработчик
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.
    /// </summary>
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {

    }


    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        // TODO Clear the ViewModels
    }
}
```

}

Дальше сделаем `ViewModel` города. Ее зависимостью будет наш `ICitiesHandler` - она же должна принять изменения от пользователя и сохранить их.

```
class CityVM : BaseVM
{
    private readonly ICitiesHandler _handler;
    private readonly City _city;

    public CityVM(City city, ICitiesHandler handler)
    {

    }

    ...

    public void Save()
    {
        // Применение изменений
        ...
        Save(_city);
    }
}
```

Вроде все сделано. Но теперь в каком-то из участков кода мне надо создать новый город. И все хорошо, если у меня есть экземпляр реализации `ICitiesHandler`, но не передавать же его в качестве зависимости всех объектам, которые могут создавать города? По идее мне хотелось бы сделать вот так:

```
var city = new CityVM();
// Далее наполняем данными и сохраняем
...
city.Save();
```

Для этого для `CityVM` я могу сделать конструктор по умолчанию, в которые в качестве модели города передать `new City()`, но вот как разрешить зависимость `ICitiesHandler`?

```
public CityVM()
    : base(new City(), ???)
{

}
```

Как быть? У меня есть два варианта.

1. Все VM запрашивать у DI-контейнера, но тогда весь слой `ViewModel` будет ссылаться на `ServiceLocator`, будь он хоть статическим классом, хоть синглтоном (который, кстати, некоторые тоже считают антипаттерном, наравне с `ServiceLocator`)
2. Или же всю функциональность по разрешению зависимости заключить в одном месте, к которому имеют доступ все `ViewModel` - это `BaseVM`. Делаем у него метод `Resolve<T>()` и тогда конструктор нового `CityVM` будет выглядеть так:

   ```
   public CityVM() : base(new City(), Resolve<ICitiesHandler>())
   ```

Что тоже не очень то мне нравится, ведь мы скрываем зависимость от программиста

В книге Марка Симана “Dependency Injection in .NET” он говорит что `SerciceLocator` использовать можно, но осторожно. При этом инкапсулировать его максимально близко к `CompositionRoot`.

Дак как быть? Что я делаю не так? Или я не тот фреймворк для этого использую?

Comment: Перед тем, как написать ответ, у меня к вам есть несколько наводящих вопросов. **1.** Почему вы считаете проблемой передачу `ICitiesHandler` в качестве зависимости всем объектам, которые могут создавать города? **2.** Зачем вам при создании нового города нужен именно `ICitiesHandler`? Вам ведь необязательно сохранять город в БД сразу при его создании? Вместо этого вы можете создать отдельный интерфейс-фабрику, который принимать как dependency во всех местах, где нужно создавать города.

Comment: **1.** Мне это кажется очень не удобным. Ведь город (населенный пункт) может создать, скажем, субъект РФ, район субъекта и т.д. При этом район субъекта может создавать может создавать субъект РФ. Получается надо передавать `ICitiesHandler` по всей цепочке. Сомнительная перспектива. **2.** Тут не понял. Мне нужно вызвать метод `Save`, чтобы эта запись создалась. Сохранится она сразу в БД или нет, меня и не должно интересовать, что происходит под капотом конкретной реализации `ICitiesHandler` не проблема в данном контексте

Comment: У Симана ServiceLocator в антипаттернах, где Вы там нашли про «можно использовать»? Автор книги не может запрещать, что-то использовать, но он явно не рекомендует этого делать. Его рекомендация, это *нестатический* IoC контейнер, которые создаёт весь граф(дерево) зависимостей в одном месте. Вот и всё. Всё остальное передаётся вниз по дереву.

Comment: @ixSci, да, он говорит что относит его к антипаттернам, но при этом там есть рекомендация про его использование, если все-таки решили

Answer (score 1):

> но не передавать же его в качестве зависимости всем объектам, которые
>   могут создавать города?

Именно так, передавать.

Судя по этому отрывку кода, `CityVM` -- это вью-модель объекта данных `City`:

```
var city = new CityVM();
// Далее наполняем данными и сохраняем
...
city.Save();
```

Если это действительно так, что `CityVM` не должна содержать метода `Save()`. Этот метод должен быть во вью-модели *экрана*, на котором вы создаете (или редактируете) город. И эта вью-модель экрана должна получать зависимость `ICitiesHandler`. В любом случае, место создания города должно быть как можно более локализовано: как на уровне UI (конкретный экран), так и на уровне кода (конкретная вью-модель экрана или сервис).

Comment: > Если это действительно так, что CityVM не должна содержать метода
> Save()

По задумке `CityVM` отображается пользователю и у нее есть команда `SaveCommand`. Можно, конечно, обернуть `CityVM` во `ViewModel` для редактирования, но мне кажется это уже лишним

Answer (score 1):

Старайтесь все, что нужно, передавать через конструктор, поэтому нормальная практика для нужных мест регистрировать фабрики. Например,  ту же фабрику вьюмоделей. IoC не обязана, да и просто не может, разрешить все зависимости. Так что фабрики, protected фабричные методы отлично дополняют IoC в практике.

Дело IoC - создать граф объектов на верхнем уровне, а ниже если ее использовать. то она по сути превращается в ServiceLocator, и если что-то нужно создавать ниже по уровням, то IoC должна не передавать себя, а инстанцировать фабрики.

Также старайтесь разделить редактирование модели и код ее чтения/хранения. Хотя это проще сказать, чем делать если нужна валидация завязанная на базу данных, а валидация в WPF неудобная

Comment: @минусатор, обоснуйте минус

Comment: можете поподробнее про фабрики? И что неудобного в валидации WPF?

Comment: @Donil Многие считают, что IoC это "универсальная фабрика", b ожидают от нее решения всех проблем (например регистрация по ключу).  IoC это конфигурируемая фабрика, но хороша только для верхнего уровня иначе превращается в ServceLocator с его недостатками. Если же нужно создавать по параметрам объекты на нижних уровнях, то это должны делать фабрики, которые и нужно регистрировать в IoC (вместо ухищрений регистрации по ключу нужно регистрировать фабрики). Конечно эта фабрика может принять в себя ссылку на IoC. Фабрика может быть и Func<>, хоть и выглядит это коряво.

Comment: @Donil WPF валидация со своими ValidationRule и IDataErrorInfo заставляет нас валидировать по их требованиям к реализации или же городить велосипед. Возьмем проверку "сущность есть в бд". Если ее запихнуть в ValidationRule, то у нас не выйдет переиспользовать эту валидацию просто в коде. А если в IDataErrorInfo, то мы привносим знание о хранении в CityVM, что неправильно. правильно создавать модель, открыть форму, нажать ок, закрыть форму и в вызывающем коде сохранить модель. То есть не модель (в своей вьюмодели) должна знать как себя сохранять. Можно прокидывать валидаторы, но это костыли.

Comment: @Donil И это общая теория. Сам я считаю уровень вьюмодей верхним уровнем, поэтому спокойно передаю IoC по вьюмоделям. Раздробленная вьюмодель - все равно один уровень для меня. То есть я стараюсь чтобы во вьюмодель меньше передавать, но если ей нужен контейнер, то передаю. В код, который лежит уровнем ниже и вызывается из вьюмоделей IoC не попадает - там уже только явные зависимости, которые видно из сигнатуры.

Comment: но я же могу зарегистрировать все `ViewModel` в di-контейнере и запрашивать каждый раз у него экземпляр. Но в таком случае опять получаем универсальную фабрику. Можете привести пример как делать правильно?

Comment: @Donil Вы меня не поняли. 1) Она и есть универсальная фабрика. Просто контейнер не должен передаваться как ServiceLocator (вьюмодели исключения в силу природы верхнего уровня, но лучше передавать зависимости,а не IoC). Если контейнер нужен ниже как локатор - резолвите и передайте явную зависимость, как фабрика - передайте конкретную фабрику (явная зависимость). 2) Если нужно создавать параметризированные вьюмодели, то не мучайтесь настройкой IoC, а напишите и зарегистрируйте классфабрику вьюмоделей. Всякие override params в IoC зло из-за магии. IoC - средство автоматизации, а не магический куб

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37402/discussion-between-vitidev-and-donil).